# Get All The youtube video from specific channel in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get video from a specific channel in youtube using youtube data api using reactjs.But my api query doesnot return anything.Here is what i've tried for getting the video.What am i doing wrong here.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount colling ...');


        fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key="MYAPIKEY"&channelId="MYCHANNELID"&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=2')
            .then(results => {
                this.setState({videos: results.json()});
                this.setState({playingVideoId: this.state.videos[this.index]});
                console.log("videos",this.state.videos)
                console.log("videos",this.state.playingVideoId)

            })
 }
```

Comment: Did you try postman to see if your URL is returning correct data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** try to use postman to see if URL is returning correct data.

**Second**: `setState` *is asynchronous* which means, if you `console.log` right after setting state, you won't get correct results. Also, your second call to `setState` is using data from first call therefore you won't get right results. Just call `setState` once and use callback to log what you got.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount colling ...');

    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key="MYAPIKEY"&channelId="MYCHANNELID"&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=2')
        .then(results => {
            const videosObj = results.json();
            this.setState({
                videos: videosObj,
                playingVideoId: videosObj[this.index]
            }, (updatedState) => {
                console.log("videos", updatedState.videos);
                console.log("videos", updatedState.playingVideoId);
            });
        })
}
```